# how to show two forms in one template who share relationship?

Tags: django

```
class Author(forms.ModelForm):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(forms.ModelForm):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

i have two modelforms who share foreignkey relationship in between and i want to show these two in one template so a user able to submit these two at once.I know how to render them through function based  and class based views but i am puzzled with that foreign key, how to represent it that when one type name in Author modelform field then it would appear in author field of Book model form?

Comment: You can use a modelformset. Check the documentation on how to implement it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question why you would want two forms. If one is editing a Book, and the Author is FK to book, one would expect the list of Authors to appear as a dropdown in the Book form, right? So, one form. This happens pretty much automatically when using ModelForm's [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) convention.

Of course this assumes that all Authors are already in the database, and/or you have a separate form on a separate view where Authors are managed. If you're asking how can you provide the ability to create new authors and edit a book at the same time, 
that's quite a bit more complicated since you'd need to (e.g.) present a New Author form in a popup, then send the results of that addition to the Authors dropdown in the Book editing form (as is done in the Django Admin).

But conventionally we assume that by the the time you get to the Book form, all Authors exist, and you can present them as choices in a dropdown.